# ASP.NET MVC VK callback API

Tags: c#, asp.net, vkontakte-api, http, tcp

Задача:
Нужно сделать ВК бота который будет делать рассылку сообщений.
Реализация на ASP.NET MVC, найдя документацию на сайте [ВК](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs), начал делать контроллер для получения данных из пост запросов от ВК.
Структура пост данных от ВК выглядит вот так:

```
{ 
   "type":"message_new", 
   "object":{ 
      "id":694, 
      "date":1499441696, 
      "out":0, 
      "user_id":123456, 
      "read_state":0, 
      "title":" ... ", 
      "body":"start" 
   }, 
   "group_id":1, 
   "secret":"sjr948dff3kjnfd3" 
}
```

пробовал создавать контроллер такого типа

```
public actionresult (string type, string object, string group, string secret)
{
  // обработка данных
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
}
```

Но это не привело ни к чему хорошему.
Далее была попытка извлечь `post` данные с помощью `request.form.tostring()`, на что успешно получал `request.form == null`.
Так же пытался вытащить все значения по ключам с помощью `Request.Params`, но всё так же безуспешно.

**Вопрос 1**:

В документации VK сказано, что от сервера должен прийти именно `post` запрос, а данные пост запроса хранятся именно в заголовках страницы, т.е. `request.form.tostring()` должен их найти в любом случае?

**Вопрос 2**:

Если сервер ВК отправит просто кусок кода `{ "type": "confirmation", "group_id": 160108907 }`, без заголовков и всего прочего, то это ведь будет уже не `post` запрос т.к. это не соответствует HTTP протоколу?

**Вопрос 3**:

Как можно получить абсолютно всю информацию о запросе через `Application_BeginRequest()`?

**Вопрос 4**:

У кого какие есть идеи, как вытащить эти магические пост данные?

Comment: Спасибо Vlad Spirin за редактирование вопроса